# Java calling a method from SuperClass in interface

Tags: java

I'm currently developing a project which requires me to control robots.

I keep them in an array of RobotInterfaces, thing is, I got a super class named RobotMovement since all movement is equal for all robots.

The robot classes that implement the RobotInterface also extend the Super Class

How do I call the method move() from the super class in the array of interfaces?

Comment: Code samples will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The robot classes that implement the RobotInterface also extend the Super Class
>
> How do I call the method move() from the super class in the array of interfaces?

You can declare the `move()` method in `RobotInterface`. That way Java will let you call `move()` on any expression of type `RobotInterface`, and Java will enforce the requirement that all instances of `RobotInterface` have an implementation of `move()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class RobotMovement {
    public void move() {
       System.out.println("moving...");
    }
}

interface RobotInterface {
    public void move(); // add this
}

class Robot extends RobotMovement implements RobotInterface {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RobotInterface> list = new ArrayList<RobotInterface>();
        list.add(new Robot());
        list.add(new Robot());
        for (RobotInterface ri: list) {
            ri.move();
        }
    }
}
```